# Use of phonegap for the development of apps on several patforms

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, cross-platform

just wanted to clear a confusion concerning phonegap,

My area of interest is mainly Android and Iphone. What I really understand about phonegap is that the phonegap app is platform independant when no native libs are ysed and thus run both on iphone and android. Thus if  i build an android app on eclipse using phonegap without using any native libs, will it run on iphone as well??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this is not exactly the case.

Phonegap enables you to write cross-platform code (HTML, JS, CSS), but when it comes to building, you have to compile this code to a specific environment for each OS. For example you can build the Android version using eclipse, and the iOS version using Xcode.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No, you will still need to build for iPhone as well.
You can use the same source code for all systems.